# Liquibase populating big integers inaccurately to table from generated changelog

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am currently busy switching over to liquibase and used the generateChangelog command to generate my tables and data for installation purposes. However, after running the changesets on a clean database the data was not as expected. Ive created a small example to illustrate the problem. The following MySQL table was used

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `value1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value2` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value3` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value4` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value5` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value6` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The table contained the following entries:

```
mysql> select * from test_table;
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| value1             | value2             | value3             | value4             | value5              | value6              |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 900000000000000000 | 900000000000000001 | 999999999999999900 | 999999999999999999 | 1000000000000000001 | 9223372036854775807 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using the liquibase generateChangelog command generated the following changesets:

```
<changeSet author="support (generated)" id="1412248645392-1">
    <createTable tableName="test_table">
        <column name="value1" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
        <column name="value2" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
        <column name="value3" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
        <column name="value4" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
        <column name="value5" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
        <column name="value6" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="support (generated)" id="1412248645392-2">
    <insert tableName="test_table">
        <column name="value1" valueNumeric="900000000000000000"/>
        <column name="value2" valueNumeric="900000000000000001"/>
        <column name="value3" valueNumeric="999999999999999900"/>
        <column name="value4" valueNumeric="999999999999999999"/>
        <column name="value5" valueNumeric="1000000000000000001"/>
        <column name="value6" valueNumeric="9223372036854775807"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

However restoring these changesets to an empty database populated the table incorrectly as follows:

```
mysql> select * from test_table;
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| value1             | value2             | value3             | value4              | value5              | value6              |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 900000000000000000 | 900000000000000000 | 999999999999999872 | 1000000000000000000 | 1000000000000000000 | 9223372036854775807 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Does anyone maybe have an explanation as to why the values are incorrect? I am using MySQL Version 5.5 and Liquibase 3.2.2 Core release.

Edited: A workaround for now seems to be populating the data by replacing "valueNumeric" with "value" in the column tags, however this does not explain why valueNumeric does not work as expected.

Comment: when I use `updateSQL` to check the script, Liquibase writes out a statement like this: `INSERT INTO test_table (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6) VALUES (9.0E17, 9.0E17, 9.9999999999999987E17, 1.0E18, 1.0E18, 9.223372036854776E18)`. If Liquibase is actually using the literals like that (instead of using a `PreparedStatemnt`) this would explain it.

Comment: Btw: are you aware that `bigint(19)` and `bigint(20)` are the same data type? The number does **not** limit the values you can put into the column. It is merely a hint for an application displaying the data on how many digits you want to see. Oh, and there is no MySQL 14.14. The current version is 5.6

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Yeah Im using 5.5 made the mistake of posting the client version... I also think the problem is some mathematical roundoff error, if this is the case it seems like I will have to go through all my scripts and change "valueNumeric" to "value" unless there is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name, Liquibase does use literals vs. prepared statements so that the updateSQL output is exactly the same as what is ran in an update

Comment: @NathanVoxland: then this is clearly a bug in Liquibase. I assume this is the result of calling `BigDecimal.toString()` instead of converting the value to a `Long` (or `BigInteger`)